# Trying to print a div every 4th loop in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, counter

I have a loop here which is publishing a full list of my custom post type - however, every 4th loop I'm trying to print a clearfix, this is what I came up with but it either prints it every single loop or none at all - can anybody lend a hand? cheers

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom',
    'numberposts' => '-1',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $postslist = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);

    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 100; $counter++ ) {
        if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
            echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
     }  
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for for loop. You can try this I hope it will be work.

```
<?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'numberposts' => '-1',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $postslist = get_posts($args);
        $count = 1 ;
        foreach ($postslist as $post) : 
        setup_postdata($post);
        if($count % 4 ==0){
          echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
         }
        $count++;
     endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't print the div

Comment: sorry I was forget $count++. Can u please try it again